# Grails 4.0.1 - Spock unit test cases fail because of spaces

Tags: grails, internationalization, spock

I am testing i18n formatting using unit tests in my Grails 4.0.1 application but seeing strange results.
To me, this specs condition should be satisfied, but it is not.

[image]

I don't suppose anyone has had a similar experience that can be explained, or maybe it's simply a bug?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It isn't obvious from the screenshot what whitespace characters are actually in the string.  You will need to interrogate those strings to identify the difference.

Comment: Just to give you and idea about possible [Unicode whitespace characters](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html)... But it may also be a problem with different character encodings on client and server.

Comment: "But it may also be a problem with different character encodings on client and server." - I don't think that is likely relevant here.  It looks like a unit test invoking a method on an object, not an HTTP request.

Comment: Replacing your current assertion with something like `formatService.formatCurrency(123456.78).bytes == '123 456,78 $'.bytes` might shed some light on the specific issue.

Comment: You are correct @JeffScottBrown. I have since figured out the problem with some good suggestions to get the hex value of each side. Answer to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an idea:

Can you iterate over both expected and actual values and convert the characters one by one to the ascii so that you'll probably see the difference

```
for( c in ​'123 456,78 $') {  
  println "$c   ${(int)c}"
}
```

Comment: Also `println '123 456,78 $'.bytes` is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It was suggested that I get the hex value of each side after which it became clear that the formatter was using a non-breaking line space `c2a0` whereas my "expected" value was using the standard kind `20`.

I have solved this by using non-breaking spaces on the "expected" side which can be achieved on the Mac by holding `Alt` + `space` button as per below.

[image]

Comment: this has a smell of wrong charachter encoding for classes in your IDE

Comment: I'm not so sure. I would not expect the IDE to use a non-breaking space unless I specifically meant to. Maybe I'm misunderstanding.