# Unexpected Spock MissingMethodException with File.createTempFile()

Tags: java, testing, groovy, spock

I have these lines in a `given` block of a test/feature:

```
log.debug( "subdir1 |$subdir1| class ${subdir1.class}")
File.createTempFile​( 'blub', 'odt', subdir1 )
```

The log message is:

```
2020-01-30 08:34:47,433 - 1404 ms [Test worker] DEBUG core.IndexCreationSpec [core.IndexCreationSpec] $spock_feature_1_26:706 
subdir1 |/tmp/junit8540540913300320698/subdir1| class class java.io.File
```

But I'm getting the following Spock fail on the `createTempFile` line:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static
>   java.io.File.createTempFile​() is applicable for argument types:
>   (String, String, File) values: [blub, odt,
>   /tmp/junit8540540913300320698/subdir1] Possible solutions:
>   createTempFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.File),
>   createTempFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), createNewFile(),
>   createTempDir(), createTempDir(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

This method of `File` is not one I use very often. There are workarounds to create Files with temporary filenames. But I'm simply baffled by the Spock fail. Is it a Spock failure (i.e. should I submit a bug report)?

***Update: analysis of string classes***

```
def blub = 'blub'
log.debug( "blub |$blub| class ${blub.class} class2 ${'blub'.class}")

2020-01-30 09:52:34,187 - 1375 ms [Test worker] DEBUG core.IndexCreationSpec [core.IndexCreationSpec] $spock_feature_1_26:709
blub |blub| class class java.lang.String class2 class java.lang.String
```

Comment: What does `log.debug('blub'.class)` show?

Comment: Thanks - see update

Comment: Does `File.createTempFile​( 'blub', 'odt', new File(subdir1.absolutePath) )` work? If so, `subdir1` is a file from a different classloader for some reason

Comment: @tim_yates Solved... see my answer

Comment: Good news, and good catch

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. It's very odd and no doubt a one-in-a-many-thousand chance of happening. But might help someone, so I propose not deleting the question.

***Somehow*** a mysterious Unicode character, `u200B`, "zero-width space" had slipped itself between `File.createTempFile` and `(`.

Removing this solved the problem! It would appear this was considered to be part of the method I was trying to call. Had I paid more attention to the Groovy formatting (Eclipse, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48083451/595305)) I would have noticed that it was underlined (= "unrecognised  method") when it should have been non-underlined and italic (= "recognised static method").

Comment: Great catch! Actually when I copy the corresponding line of code from your question into a simple text editor like Notepad++ and move the cursor with left/right cursor keys, I can see how the zero-width space is actually contained in the method call. The cursor position count changes, counting the character, but the cursor does not move horizontally. So at least we know that Unicode on StackOverflow works flawlessly. ;-) Nobody could have answered that by just reading the question, which is why [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s are so essential.

Comment: BTW, this seems to be the week of white-space-related Spock questions, see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59946271/1082681) I commented just 5 days ago, even posting a link to a list of [Unicode whitespace characters](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html) which also contains your `u200B`.

Comment: Yes, that business of the cursor not moving was how I managed to detect it in Eclipse... so then I copied to a site which tells you what Unicode string you've pasted.